# RxJava Observable that emits latest value upon subscription

Tags: java, android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I am building an Android MVVM application using RxJava2. What I want is to expose an `Observable` in my ViewModel, which I also can receive the last emitted value (like a `BehaviourSubject`). I don't want to expose a `BehaviourSubject` because I don't want the View to be able to call `onNext()`.

For example, in my `ViewModel` I expose a date. I now want to subscribe a `TextView` to changes, but I also need to be able to access the current value if I want to show a `DatePickerDialog` with this date as initial value.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Delegate:

```
class TimeSource {
    final BehaviorSubject<Long> lastTime = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(
        System.currentTimeMillis());

    public Observable<Long> timeAsObservable() {
        return lastTime;
    }

    public Long getLastTime() {
        return lastTime.getValue();
    }

    /** internal only */
    void updateTime(Long newTime) {
        lastTime.onNext(newTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: by the way, to hide the publishing capabilities of lastTime, you would want to do upådate timeAsObservable() with "return lastTime.hide()"

This way, only the observable is exposed outside.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't want to expose a [`BehaviourSubject`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/subjects/BehaviorSubject.html)

[`Subject`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/subjects/Subject.html), by definition, is *"an `Observer` and an `Observable` at the same time"*. Therefore, instead of exposing `BehaviorSubject` itself just expose `Observable`, thus client (in this case the view) won't be able to perform `onNext()`, but will be able to receive last emitted value.

As an alternative to subject approach you can use `replay(1).autoConnect()` approach. See more details concerning this approach in ["RxJava by example" presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wxx9hEi_E8c) by Kaushik Gopal.

Also, consider `cache()` operator (see difference of `cache` and `replay().autoConnect()` [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/5704)).